# Change HTML on page based on Address? (PHP or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, get

I need a single page on a server that will either have "false" or "true" written to it.

But, I need that page to edit itself based on the address. So for example, if I were to navigate to `http://domain.com/file.html?item=true` I would need the page to change the value to "true" by itself so that once I navigated to `http://domain.com/file.html` I would need to see "true" written on the page. Or if I navigated to `http://domain.com/file.html?item=false` it would automatically change to "false" so that once I navigated to `http://domain.com/file.html` I would see "false" written on the page.

This is for an arduino project where I am having the arduino monitor the file and if the file states "false" then it does nothing. If the file states "true", it starts blinking an LED. Since I want this to be wireless, I am going to host it on a server and have the arduino check for the status of the item on the file online. Or I might host the webserver directly on the arduino. The entire arduino part I know how to do. Just don't know about the file on the server with the "true" or "false" value.

I honestly have no idea how to do this with either PHP or Javascript.

Can someone help, please? :)

Comment: Try using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: @Oriol Sessions won't work because OP wants to set the value from his machine and then read it from the Arduino.

Comment: What about cookies? @IngoBürk

Comment: @IngoBürk True, I didn't understand well the situation. Idris, cookies have the same problem as sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the value in a text file on the server:

```
<?php
$filename = "current.txt";

if(isset($_GET['item'])) {
  $item = $_GET['item'];
  if($item !== "true" && $item !== "false") {
      die("attempted to write illegal value");
  }

  file_put_contents($filename, $item);
}

echo file_get_contents($filename);
?>
```

However, this feels really hacky and workaroundy, not like good solution. It's basically a simple "text file database".

I don't really know anything about Arduinos, but why don't you build up an actual connection to the Arduino, send it the value and have it store the current value itself? I'm sure that's possible.

Comment: It's possible, yes, but I want this to be wireless. I am trying to create a physical notification device to light up a light when I have notification on my phone. If I were to connect my phone to the arduino (very possible), I could just check for notifications on my phone manually. So I am trying to create a wireless system where my phone checks for notifications, sends a command, and then the arduino acts upon that command by checking the file and acting upon the value inside the file.

Comment: A connection can still be wireless ;) you mentioned hosting the server on the Arduino. Wouldn't that mean you directly connect the phone to the device anyway? I still don't see why your phone, instead of sending the request to some Webserver, doesn't just send the request to the Arduino directly. But hey, it's your project. Does my answer help you? If so please consider marking it as accepted.